Process for reading planner checklist items via microsoft.graph.models?
Hello and thanks for any advice you can offer. I am attempting to read planner checklist items through a thin client application.
I have reviewed the API documentation and understand that I'm dealing with PlannerTask, PlannerTaskDetails, PlannerCheckListItems (a collection) and PlannerCheckListItem and that what I am after is PlannerCheckListItem.Title.
I have successfully retrieved the Plannertask and PlannerTaskDetails but I'm having trouble navigating from there down to a PlannerCheckListItem
if (taskDetails.Checklist != null)
 {
 foreach (var keyValuePair in taskDetails.Checklist.AdditionalData)
  {
   var checklistItem = keyValuePair.Value;
  }  

       

checklistItem is a structure containing the checklist item, but I do not know how to access it. When I watch this in the debugger I see Non Public Members, _properties, and then five properties [0],1 etc and [2] each leading to a Key and Value containing the checklist information.
See snip.
Can anyone give me advice on how to complete this last step and pullout the checklist data? I can't find a method built into the API for this, but it seems like there should be?
thank you.
checklistitems debug watch
